# How to make grid of elements in iOS?

Tags: ios

So I'm about to make an app for iOS in xCode (go figure), and I am curious as to what people would suggest to do here.

My goal is to create a grid of buttons mxn in dimensions. I recently made a tic tac toe game variation where I had an overall 9x9 grid of buttons. It was very tedious work to create each button.

Would there be an easier way to create all these buttons through code?

Comment: That would be a good point to make.. EDITED iOS, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `for` loop to create the buttons. May be something of the following sorts to create a buttons for 3X3 grid

```
CGFloat xAxis,yAxis,bWidth,bHeight;
xAxis = 0.0;
yAxis = 0.0;
bWidth = 150.0;
bHeight = 44.0;
int numberOfRows = 3;
int numberOfColumns = 3;
int number = 1;

for(int i=0;i<numberOfRows;i++)
{
     for(int j=0;j<numberOfColumns;j++)
   {
      UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xAxis, yAxis, bWidth, bHeight)];
      button.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",number];
      number++;
      [self.view addSubview:button];
      xAxis = xAxis  + bWidth + 5.0;
   }
   xAxis = 0;
   yAxis = yAxis +  bHeight + 5.0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`IBOutletCollection`s are a good candidate here, if you have a reasonable number of buttons. You can then loop through all of them to apply the same properties.